# What is the ordinary generating function of this series?

Tags: generating-functions

I need this as part of a bigger proof.

Does 
\begin{align}
G_1 &\longleftrightarrow \Big\{\binom{n}{k}\Big\}_{2k=0}^r \notag \\
\implies G_1(z) &= (1 + z^2)^r 
\end{align}

Help me prove this as it would help me with the bigger problem I'm doing.

I know the ordinary generating function of $\Big\{\binom{r}{k}\Big\}_{k=0}^r$ is $(1 + z)^r$.

---

Here is the original problem and my working.

Find a generating function $G(z)$ for which $$[z^n]G(z) = \sum_{k_0 + 2k_1 + 4k_2 + 8k_3 + \dots =n} \binom{r}{k_0}\binom{r}{k_1}\binom{r}{k_2}\binom{r}{k_3}\dots$$

The fact that all the sum of all the indices of summation is always constant suggests that $G(z)$ is the product of several different generating functions.
\begin{align}
\text{The generating function of }G_1 &\longleftrightarrow \Big\{\binom{r}{k_0}\Big\}_{k_0 = 0}^r \notag \\
\implies G_1(z) &= (1+z)^r \\
\text{The generating function of }G_2 &\longleftrightarrow \Big\{\binom{r}{k_1}\Big\}_{2k_1 = 0}^r \notag \\
\implies G_2(z) &= (1+z^2)^r \\
\text{The generating function of }G_3 &\longleftrightarrow \Big\{\binom{r}{k_2}\Big\}_{4k_2 = 0}^r \notag \\
\implies G_3(z) &= (1+z^4)^r\\
\vdots \notag \\
\text{The generating function $G(z)$ can be gotten by multiplying all these functions}G(z) &= G_1(z)G_2(z)G_3(z)\dots \notag \\
&=(1+z)^r(1+z^2)^r(1+z^4)^r\dots \notag \\
\implies G(z) &=\Big(\frac{1}{1-z}\Big)^r \\
\text{Now, we have gotten the generating function. The sum is }&\binom{r+n-1}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: What is $\Big\{\binom{n}{k}\Big\}_{2k=0}^r$?

Comment: @RossMillikan It's a sequence of numbers. $G_1(z)$ is the generating function of that sequence.

Comment: @RossMillikan Please help me, Ross. You can do it.

Comment: In your last, it is only $(1+z)^r$ if $r=n$.  Is that true in the case you want?

Comment: @RossMillikan That was a typo

Comment: @RossMillikan I just need to know if $(1+z^2)^r$ is the generating function if the index increases by $2$ and not $1$.

Comment: Maybe the sequence you meant is $\left\{\binom n{2k}\right\}_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Not really. But, is that what the generating function $G_1(z)$ generates ?

Comment: If you'd like I could post the proof I'm actually working on, but it's big and I only have a doubt here.

Comment: @user230452 The point is that what you wrote is meaningless. I have voted to close until what is written there is standard notation.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Which part is not standard according to you ?

Comment: It is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I understand if you don't want to help, but I don't know what you'll gain from closing it and ensuring nobody else can either.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have uploaded the original problem and my working too to show where I needed that lemma from.

Answer (score 1):

By the Binomial theorem,

$$(1+z^2)^r=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom rkz^{2k}$$ hence $G_{1,2k}=\binom rk$ and $G_{1,2k+1}=0$.

Comment: I don't understand what the subscripts are ? What do they represent ?

Comment: @user230452: are you serious ?

Comment: Yes, you are using two subscripts. That's what's confusing me.

Comment: @user230452 The first is yours !

Comment: Ok, thanks. ${}$